# How to .move() a selected brush?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**TL;DR:** how do you move `d3.select('#a_brush')`?

#### Question

I have brushes inside `<g>` groups called `axes`. Each `<g>` axis contains a d3 axis and a d3 brush. In an update selection on `axes`, I want to update the d3 axis and brush.

```
axes.each(function (d) { d3.select(this).select('.axis').call(d3.axisBottom(d[1])) });
axes.each(function (d) { d3.select(this).select('.brush').call(brush.move, f(d)) });
```

In the above, `axes` is an update selection. Assume `f(d)` yields an appropriate array. The first of the two lines works, but the second throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'move' of undefined
```

That might be because there's no variable I've saved anywhere called brush. I'm hoping to **call the `.move` method directly on the selection without having to save a brush variable**.

What is the appropriate nomenclature to move the brush in the selection

```
axes.each(function (d) { d3.select(this).select('.brush') ?? ... somehow move the brush to f(d) ...
```

#### Notes

- [d3 brush.move() docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brush_move)
- ["Click-to-Recenter Brush" Block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6498000) and [Brush & Zoom](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172) have a `.call(brush.move` with a saved `brush` variable.
- [Brush Snapping III](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b0d0aa4df3b5c3c0fa37d4b3f2127740) and [Brush Snapping II](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6232620)
   have `d3.select(this).call(d3.event.target.move,` but I may not be moving the brush from any recent d3 event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely should define a variable (or a constant) for your brush, like:

```
const brush = d3.brush();
```

That way, you don't need to customise the extent and other parameters every time. However, if for whatever reason you really don't want to do that, just change `brush` for `d3.brush()`:

```
d3.select(this).select('.brush').call(d3.brush().move, f(d))
```

Here is a basic demo, click the button to move the brush:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");

const g = svg.append("g");

g.call(d3.brush());

d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
  g.call(d3.brush().move, [
    [100, 0],
    [400, 100]
  ])
})
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<br>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

Comment: the reason I don't save the brush to a variable is because I have many brushes, defined in an enter selection: `.each(function (d) { d3.select(this).call(d3.brushX().extent(...).on("start", brushstart).on("brush", brush).on("end", brushend) ) })`. Should I be making an array or object of brushes to hold onto them?

Comment: Yes, you should.